# Looping or Recursive PHP Function on time delay - Need Event Loop? Forking?

Tags: php, mysql, multiprocessing, daemon, pcntl

I have a PHP function that needs to be executed ~10 seconds after certain events.

The Function can in turn create a new instance of the event, which would need to trigger the function again ~10 seconds later.

Often the function won't create a new event, but it will be possible for chains in length up to ~1000. (10,000 sec) Thus - I don't think it's reasonable to contain the whole chain within a single sleep-looping php process. (is this incorrect?)

At any given time, there could be up to 100 separate instances of these event-function chains all running simultaneously.

I've been doing lots of research on reactphp / system_daemon / pcntl / fake-forking with exec() and other potential solutions. Wondering what the best solution for this sort of problem could be.

I'll also need some way to catch broken chains or timed-out long-processes, to try to restart them within the 10 second window.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you'd be better served by using a queue, e.g. https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk

Answer (score 2):

I would look into Gearman. It is a queue based system. You have worker threads that do the actual processing and clients that pass the information to the workers. This way you can for example fetch 10 web pages all at the same time. This may be helpful for you because you can program it to run 5 iterations then restart (to prevent memory leaks or hanging).

I have used it on Ubuntu and CentOS servers with great success. Whether you are doing mail queues or connecting to an API that requires only one call to run at a time, it is great for these tasks.

EDIT: You can also run Java, Python, or other progamming languages that get started from a PHP client. Great for connecting various programming languages together. If you are scared of memory leaks I would try and to the processing in another language. But I have no clue what your end task is so I wouldn't be able to help out much more than this.

Answer (score 1):

10 seconds are a long time, so I would store it into a queue in MySQL, which contains an earliest execution time and the information for the event, maybe in serialized form. This means that there are roughly 10 seconds, maybe also 11 seconds, and that even 12s do not mean desaster.

The table looks simply like

```
create table stored_events (start_at datetime, event text);
```

You read in a 1-second-queue

```
select * from stored_events where start_at <= now();
```

and you write

```
insert into stored_event set start_at = now() + interval 10 second, event='<event>'";
```

Comment: I would still need some script that runs every second. Ok to just throw it into a Cron and loop every second with time_sleep_until ? Bad practice to run all those selects every second?

Comment: How many requests (so not new visits, but new pages) do you expect per second? I do not think that a simple straight indexed single-table-query per second should be any problem. I think it would be bad to start a complete PHP every second, this is true, so there could be a looping "demon" (not sure if php is ready for this) or you make 60 loops, each a second, and start the plain new job then. But the SQL-side is definitely no problem, if the table is indexed. You never find a lot of entries, and the work for an event will be a bit more then the simple data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a cron job and a database to control the instatiations of the php? Every 10 seconds, a cron job could run, check the necessity of creating N instatiations, and instantiate them with curl or fork.

Comment: Attention: every 10 second would mean 91 seconds in worst case. This might be perfectly well, but is around 90% off the original 10 seconds from question.

Comment: Well, he could the store the events with a schedule time (something like 10 seconds after the event creation). The cron job could ask every one second if there is an event scheduled to run on that moment. Depending on how many events scheduled for that exact moment, the sub-routines would be fired.

Comment: I mean 19 seconds of course, not 91. ;-) and yes, if the cron runs every second, it could be 11 seconds.

Comment: If you are talking about using cron jobs that are built into linux this wont work. Linux cron jobs only run every minute at most. I may be wrong but I don't think any linux system supports running cron jobs more frequently than in minute increments. 

It may be better to have a program dedicated to doing these specific tasks.